# Fluid trainer works with quick release rear axles, I have a standard nut fixie

Tags: quick-release, fixed-gear

I have no experience with bike trainers.

I bought a fluid bike trainer to use with my fixie.

The trainer is for a quick release rear wheel, and comes with a special quick release skewer.

My fixie has standard track nuts. Any ideas on how to solve this?

[image: The trainer cups over the standard track nut, but it's not a perfect fit.]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the trainer, in particular the area where the axle interfaces with the trainer

Comment: I added a photo. It fits over the track nut, just not perfectly. As you can see it bows a bit.

Comment: It depends on the manufacturer as to what they recommend. Also, you won't really be able to get good resistance with a trainer for a fixie -- if you want to train indoors, you're better off with rollers.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the Cycle Ops Fluid 2 trainer, which is what I have, you can use it with nutted wheels.  The skewer that comes with it is just for bikes with fancy quick release skewers that don't fit into the trainer or if you have nice skewers that you don't want to scratch up.

For nutted wheels, the retaining mechanism should fit fine over top of the nuts.

## Update

Thanks for the picture.

That isn't the Cycle Ops Fluid Trainer, so it looks like my previous info isn't really applicable.  Some trainers aren't designed to work with nutted wheels.  Looks like it's not only a problem with the way it mounts, but that your hub is too narrow.  The mechanism looks like it's screwed all the way in, but it's still too loose.  How much axle/bolt do you have sticking out from the nut? It looks like the part that's supposed go around the nut/skewer isn't very deep, and is probably meeting up with the end of the axle.  You could probably cut it shorter to alleviate this problem, but that's probably not an optimal solution.

There's a couple different adapters that I was able to find for using nutted axles in trainers linked below. It's difficult to tell if either one would work with your specific trainer.

[Forza Bolt Axle Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0037NBYGG)

[TACX axle nuts](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/ca/en/tacx-axle-nuts/rp-prod43717)

Even if you do manage to get it mounted properly, it might not work that well. I mounted my fixie on my trainer once, and there wasn't enough resistance. Fluid trainers generally don't have adjustable resistance (maybe yours does) and required that you change gears to adjust the resistance. I found that the gear on my fixie (46x15, which is higher than most) wasn't hard enough to give me a decent workout on my trainer.

Comment: Unrelated to this question but this is the only place on the internet where I've found a definitive answer to "can I use the Fluid2 without quick-release wheels". It comes with a warning to the effect of "don't use the trainer without _this specific skewer_ because otherwise you will die and possibly awaken the elder gods"